# Is the Belters' accent based on any non-fiction accent?

Tags: the-expanse-2015

When Belters in The Expanse speak English, they do so with a particular accent. It sounds vaguely familiar to me, but I cannot identify it. I'm not a native English speaker myself.

Is that accent based on any non-fiction accent? Which one?

Ideal answers would quote the artists involved, but lacking that, your opinion as a listener is welcome.

I'm aware of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170403/what-is-the-belter-language-accent-based-on) with a great answer about their language, but nothing about the accent.

Comment: This is a dupe of [What is the Belter language/accent based on?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170403/what-is-the-belter-language-accent-based-on)

Comment: I fail to see what the difference is between a question asking about "language/accent" and your question. If you're not happy with the answers on that one, you can always post a bounty.

Comment: @Valorum It does not. It has a great answer about their language, but nothing about the accent.

Comment: That question asks about the language *and* accent. The fact that you feel that the existing answers don't address your question about the accent strongly enough isn't sufficient incentive for you to post a duplicate question.

Comment: @Valorum If I do post a bounty on the larger scope question, can I narrow the answers eligible to the bounty? Am I not bound by the scope of the question?

Comment: I would probably choose **"Improve details: The current answers do not contain enough detail."** as your bounty option and then write a custom reason such as *"I am placing a bounty on answers that more closely address the subject of the accents used or chosen by the actors, ideally providing quotes from the artists themselves"*